# ADFS 1021 error - MSIS9422: Received invalid OAuth JWT Bearer request

Tags: windows, server, adfs

I'm new employee trying to figure out what is going in in our ADFS. What I'm trying to enable is single sign on (SSO) for a couple application portals. In my ADFS I have both hybrid as well as azure AD joined users.

My event log is spammed full with 1021 errors:

```
Encountered error during OAuth token request.
```

Additional Data

```
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthInvalidGrantException: MSIS9422: Received invalid OAuth JWT Bearer request. The certificate used to sign JWT Bearer request is not from a registered device. ---> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthInvalidGrantException: MSIS9422: Received invalid OAuth JWT Bearer request. The certificate used to sign JWT Bearer request is not from a registered device.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.ValidateDeviceObject(DRDevice device)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.CreateUserToken()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.ValidateJWTBearer()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.ValidateJWTBearer()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.ValidateCore()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.ProtocolContext.Validate()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthTokenProtocolHandler.ProcessJWTBearerRequest(OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext jwtBearerContext)

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthInvalidGrantException: MSIS9422: Received invalid OAuth JWT Bearer request. The certificate used to sign JWT Bearer request is not from a registered device.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.ValidateDeviceObject(DRDevice device)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.CreateUserToken()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthToken.OAuthJWTBearerRequestContext.ValidateJWTBearer()
```

As far as I can tell device auth is turned off... I have it work for one application but we can't seem to figure out why it wouldn't work with other applications that I know support SSO.

If more information is need please let me know!

Thanks.